# Accessing Services using SSH fails in PCFDev

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have a PCFDev VM and I've a `p-mysql` instance binding to `my-app`. I'm trying to access the `mysql` instance through `SSH` but get this cryptic error:

```
<prompt> cf create-service-key.....
<prompt> cf service-key .......
<prompt> cf ssh -N -L 63306:<hostname>:3306 my-app
Failed
Error:EOF
```

Can't find anything via Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bleh..you can't access via ssh if the app is not running..in my case it was in crashed state!

Comment: Seems like the legit answer - you should accept it even if it's your own!